# How do I deserialize to object with json.net (instead of JObject)

Tags: c#, json.net

Using json.net this test fails by default:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object()), 
    typeof(object)
).ShouldBeOfType<object>(); // actual type is JObject
```

Is there a way to change this behavior, so it deserializes to the actual requested type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a degenerate test case there.  If you instruct Json.Net to deserialize into type `object`, you are telling it that the JSON could represent any possible object.  So it will choose to use a `JObject` in that case, since you were not specific and a `JObject` can handle any JSON object.  It is not expecting that you want to deserialize into a literal empty `object` instance, because that is not a very useful thing to do.  If the JSON contained any data at all, you would not be able to access that data after the deserialization: `object` has no properties!

You can fix your test by creating an empty class `Foo` and using that in place of `object`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo()), typeof(Foo)
).ShouldBeOfType<Foo>();
```

---

If you really do need to force Json.Net to deserialize into an empty `object` instance whenever `object` is specified as the type, you can do it using a custom `JsonConverter` like this:

```
public class EmptyObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);  // consume the JSON object from the reader 
        return token.Type == JTokenType.Null ? null : new object();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then pass an instance of the converter to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object()), 
    typeof(object),
    new EmptyObjectConverter()
).ShouldBeOfType<object>();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7xZ7tm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but deserialising into an empty object is actually what I want to do, as the test case reflects. I can see why this is not usually useful and I understand the chosen behavior, but I would like to be able to change it. I need to have an instance of the same type on both sides and that type can sometimes be object. I can of course wrap it, check the given type and create the object myself if needed, but I just wondered, if there was a "built in" way. I was not able to do it with a custom contract resolver, but I might have overlooked something.

Comment: You can do what you want with a custom JsonConverter.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: You might want to check for `reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null`.  Currently `JObject.Parse("null");` throws an exception rather than returning null.

Comment: Ah yes, why didn't I think of that, that's exactly it. Thanks! :)